# Spring annotation 3.0 Multiple attributes handling

Tags: spring-mvc, annotations

I am new to Spring 3.0 with Annotations.

*I have added a new attribute which should be referred in the new jsp however it keeps referring to old attribute.*

Comment: while asking a question be as verbose as you can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're question is too vague to answer definitively, so here are some thoughts. Post your code and expand on your question to get a better response.

In your controller you should be adding the attribute to the model, such as:

```
@Controller("myController")
public class MyController {
   @RequestMapping("/mypage")
   public String handleMyPage(Model model){
      model.put( "theattribute", new SomeObject() );
      return "mypage"
   }
}
```

My guesses and suggestions:

- You are returning a reference to an "old" JSP that hasn't been updated to display something new
- Check that the controller you expect is actually handling the request, perhaps you have a simple bug where a different controller is handling the request and doing something you didn't expect
- Add some debug statements to ensure that what you are putting into the model is what you really think you are putting in there.
- Start simplifying your controller down to its basics. Load a new JSP page which just outputs the value of this single object, and trim down your controller until it only adds this one object, then start adding things back into both until you run across the problem, this will help you reduce the possible problem areas.

Once you've done some of that try another question with more specifics regarding what you've tried and where you are.